# java - how to calculate the excess days of 2 dates

Tags: java, database, netbeans

i have a script that show the different of the dates but the one i need it is to get 0 day if 'tglkembali' is lower than 'tempo' but the script i type is calculating the both ways

```
try{
    String tglsatu = tempo.getText();
    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date tglAwal = (Date) date.parse(tglsatu);
    String tgldua = tglKembali.getText();
    Date tglAkhir = (Date) date.parse(tgldua);

    long bedaHari = tglAkhir.getTime() - tglAwal.getTime();
    terlambat.setText(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(bedaHari) + " hari");

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()` wil be handy for your task.

Comment: An `if`-`else` statement? If the difference is negative, print 0 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

```
    try {
        String tglSatu = "2019-01-07";
        LocalDate tglAwal = LocalDate.parse(tglSatu);
        String tglDua = "2019-01-18";
        LocalDate tglAkhir = LocalDate.parse(tglDua);

        long bedaHari = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(tglAwal, tglAkhir);
        if (bedaHari < 0) {
            bedaHari = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("" + bedaHari + " hari");

    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe){
         System.out.println(dtpe.getMessage());
    }
```

When the days are in the expected order, as in the snippet above, the output should agree with yours:

> 11 hari

However, If I change this line so the dates are swapped:

```
        String tglDua = "2018-12-29";
```

Now the output from my code is what you requested:

> 0 hari

Corner case: When I say the output is the same in the former case, this is only most often true. You used `Date.getTime` and `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays`, so you performed a conversion from milliseconds to days assuming a day is always 24 hours long. This is not always the case. For example, in the spring when summer time (DST) begins in some countries, the day is typically only 23 hours, which will cause your code to count a day too few. The `LocalDate` class that I use neither has got time of day nor time zone, so evades this problem.

The other reason why I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is it is generally much nicer to work with than the old date and time classes, including `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those had some design problems, and there’s no reason why we should still struggle with them.

An alternative option is to compare the dates using `isBefore` or `isAfter` and show a message if they are not in the expected order. For example (with assistance from Google Translate):

```
        if (tglAkhir.isBefore(tglAwal)) {
            System.out.println("Tanggal berada dalam urutan yang salah");
        } else {
            long bedaHari = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(tglAwal, tglAkhir);
            System.out.println("" + bedaHari + " hari");
        }
```

**Links:**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=id&text=Dates%20are%20in%20the%20wrong%20order).

Comment: ah, thank you sir. it help me a lot for beginner like me. Thanks again